# Fixed column table like structure

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a table like structure without using table,tr,td etc tags. The table should have its first column and headers fixed. I have fiddled it under this URL: http://jsfiddle.net/RtfZu/.

I am not able to create a vertical scroll-bar, which upon scrolling should scroll the frozen column too.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, i have created a jQuery plugin that would render table using  tags. The table is configurable too. code4devs.com is the URL

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your .table-body-scroll div scrollable.  In the fiddle it breaks due to the a width issue causing a double scroll bar, but you should be able to fix that by adjusting the width and setting the overflow-x to hidden

```
.table-body-scroll
{    
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RtfZu/3/

Comment: Thanks Ben. I realize that. But the number of columns in the table are dynamic. That's why I have set to the max width 1080px. WIth your solution, would it be possible to scroll the frozen column too?

Comment: probably not.  Sorry I didn't understand the requirements exactly.

Comment: By the way, i have created a jQuery plugin that would render table using <div> tags. The table is configurable too. http://www.code4devs.com is the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow-y: auto;` and define a `height` to your `.table` element.  This should scroll the entire table

Comment: That would scroll the headers which I want to make it fixed when scrolled vertically.